# ¿Como arreglo este problema en un if?

Tags: javascript

¿alguien sabe por que me sale este error y como solucionarlo?

Quiero crear un campo vacio y que cuando yo escriba algo me cree un titulo y me inicie otra tarea, pero me da error en la consola y no se como arreglarlo, la linea 13 es la del if.

```
const tasks = [];
let time = 0;
let timer = null;
let timerbreak= null;
let current = null;

const bAdd =document.querySelector('#bAdd')
const itTask =document.querySelector('itTask')
const form =document.querySelector('#form')

form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(itTask.value != ''){
        createTask(itTask.value);
        itTask.value = '';
        renderTasks();
    }
});
```

Adjunto tambien lo que estoy seleccionando en el html del itTask

```
<div class="tasks-contaniner">
             <div class="form">
                 <form action="" id="form">
                     <input type="text" id="itTask">
                     <input type="submit" id="bAdd" value="Agregar tarea">
                 </form>
             </div>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué se supone que estás seleccionado con esto: `const itTask =document.querySelector('itTask')`? Muéstranos también el HTML ligado a este código.

Comment: ```const itTask =document.querySelector('itTask')``` , aquí no estás seleccionando el input, te falta el "#" delante para seleccionarlo por su id. Debería quedar así ```const itTask =document.querySelector('#itTask')```